# What is this weird 2 prong outlet in my kitchen?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

House was built in 1964. Located above (but off center) the range. Took the plate off and it is just a hot and a neutral wire behind it.

What is this outlet for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Once again, geographical location might help. Not seen this in U.K.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The common socket you see everywhere is a NEMA 5-15. If you delete ground that's a NEMA 1-15.  That there is a NEMA 1-15 socket for a wall clock.

Note the recessed outlet style, that's so the plug will fit and still let the clock rest flush against the wall.  Also the hook to hang it on.

Also useful for neon signs e.g. ones seen at taverns.

NEC says on kitchen countertop receptacle circuits, the only other loads allowed on them are the auxiliary loads of a gas range, and a wall clock.  So it may be on a receptacle circuit.

Answer (score 3):

As Harper - Reinstate Monica says, this is a 1-15 clock outlet; historically common and now (in 5-15 form, ie grounded) seeing a bit of a resurgence for wall-mounted TVs.

Some regional codes specify that they can be on the same circuit as the fridge. This means that if you get home and your clock is behind, you can see exactly how long the fridge was without power. (And if your guests notice that you've got an AC wall clock, they can see how long it's been since you reno'd your kitchen.)

(Would have made this a comment but I don't have the rep.)